# PHP: как скачать большой файл с удалённого сервера?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Не являюсь специалистом в HTML и PHP, но нужно реализовать следующую задачу: добавить на сайт возможность скачивать mp3-файлы напрямую (без воспроизведения через браузер). Нашёл способ в использовании php-файла. Проблема в том, что чем больше размер файла, тем дольше ожидание начала скачивания; а если размер файла > 200 MB выпадает ошибка php. Как можно устранить эту проблему? Может есть более подходящие варианты, помимо использования php-файла... Спасибо.

HTML:

```html
<a href="d.php?file=http://remoteserver/1.mp3">Скачать</a>
```

d.php:

```html
<?php   
    $file = $_GET['file'];
    $file = str_replace(' ', '%20', $file);
    $ch = curl_init($file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);     
    
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);      
    curl_close($ch); 
    if ($status == 200) {   
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public'); 
        header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output));  
        echo $output;
        die();
    }            
?>
```

Comment: Пробовали смореть в сторону проксирования файла через NGINX?

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой, чем больше файл тем дольше ожидание начало скачивание файла.
Подскажите пожалуйста, по средствам чего можно решить проблему ?
Спасибо.

Comment: На бэке запихать его в zip, и уже его дать скачать.

Answer (score 0):

Данную проблему можно решить на HTML, добавив атрибут `download`:

```
 <a href="http://remoteserver/1.mp3" download>Скачать</a>
```

Подержка данного [атрибута](https://caniuse.com/#search=download)

Comment: в отношении mp3-файлов этот атрибут не поможет: большинство браузеров всё-равно будут воспроизводить файл.

Comment: Посмотрел, доку по данному атрибуту, он работает только есть у файла и сайта совпадает origin или `Content-Disposition: download` :(

Comment: а как это реализовать?

Comment: Я бы предложил попробовать смотреть в сторону проксирования через Nginx, хотя точного ответа дать не могу. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Вечером поэксперементирую если получиться напишу как сделать.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!